# how to change the value number to a word

Tags: php

I need to display true or false not the number 1

```
 $permission === 1 ? true: false
```

Comment: Well if you want to display them you probably want to use strings and not boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nearly right:

```
 $permission= ($permission === 1) ? 'true': 'false';

 echo  $permission;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

First you dont make any assignment `=`
then you have to make a comparison `$permission === 1` 
then you want the string values `"true"` or `"false"`

Answer (score 0):

change the boolean to string value

```
 $permission === 1 ? 'true': 'false';
```

Comment: @Dagon sorry didn't get

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as

```
echo "Output : ".($permission == 1) ? 'true': 'false';
```